# Make {newenvironment} and {renewenvironment} synonyms of {environments}

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Some time ago, the [newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newcommand) and [renewcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renewcommand) tags as well as the [commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commands) tag were merged with [macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros). As a complement, I propose to make [newenvironment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newenvironment) and [renewenvironment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renewenvironment) synonyms of [environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/environments) and to merge the existing tags.

Comment: I'm in favor of merging them.

Comment: The majority of {environment} questions is about defining new environments anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the question has reached a score of +4 and has some positive and no negative comments, I ask a moderator to implement my proposal.

Comment: 'Tis done

Comment: @Joseph: The 18 questions currently tagged with {newenvironment} still need to merged into {environments}.

Comment: I've done that now too